# Computing sum of progressively-increasing values in Excel

Tags: excel, math, worksheet-function, financial

I am trying to solve an iterative problem in Excel. I want to be able to calculate the sum of rent for `x` years. The rent is increasing at a rate of 10 percent every year. I quickly came up with this python code on a REPL for clarity:

```
year = 6
rent = 192000
total_rent = rent
for x in range(1 , year):
    rent= rent + .1*rent
    total_rent = total_rent + rent
print(total_rent) # 1481397.12 is what it prints
```

This is a trivial problem in programming but I am not sure the best way to achieve this in excel.

In excel I am doing it this something like this:
[image]

But all the intermediate rent amount(s) are not really needed. I guess there should be a for loop here as well too, but is there a mathematical representation of this problem which I can use to create the expected result?

Comment: Mathematically its: `initial_rent * ((1 + rate) ^ years)`, where rate is a decimal, eg `0.1` as in your example.

Comment: it's `sum(rent * 1.1**n for n in range(6))`. Does this help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do recurring deposit calculations accurately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626271/how-to-do-recurring-deposit-calculations-accurately)

Comment: I am sure this is not same which is mentioned as duplicate

Comment: How are you going to point this as a dupe to a closed question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series) where the initial term is `a = 192000` and the common ratio is `r = 1.1`. (The ratio is not just the 10% added, it includes the 100% that is added to.) To refresh your Algebra II memory, a geometric series is

```
total = a + a*r + a*r**2 + ... + a*r**(n-1)
```

The closed-form formula for the sum of the geometric series is

```
total = a * (r**n - 1) / (r - 1)
```

(using Python syntax), or, using something closer to Excel syntax,

```
total = a * (r^n - 1) / (r - 1)
```

where `n` is the number of years. Just substitute your values for `a`, `r`, and `n`.

Comment: This is the exact answer to this question, Explained perfectly in the context of mathematics. Thanks :) . Just a suggestion please change it to total = a * (r^n - 1) / (r - 1) .  Meaning change  ** to ^

Comment: @Count: I had considered that. I compromised just now, showing both versions.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a financial problem, you might try the financial functions of excel.

`=-FV(0.1, 6, 192000)`

or

`=FV(0.1, 6, -192000)`

the detail: [`FV` on Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fv-function-2eef9f44-a084-4c61-bdd8-4fe4bb1b71b3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

---

### Description

**`FV`**, one of the financial functions, calculates the **future value of an investment based on a constant interest rate**. You can use FV with either periodic, constant payments, or a single lump sum payment.

### Syntax

`FV(rate, nper, pmt, [pv], [type])`

For a more complete description of the arguments in **`FV`** and for more information on annuity functions, see **`PV`**.

The FV function syntax has the following arguments:

`Rate`    *Required*

- The interest rate per period.

`Nper`    *Required*

- The total number of payment periods in an annuity.

`Pmt`    *Required*

- The payment made each period; it cannot change over the life of the annuity. Typically, pmt contains principal and interest but no other fees or taxes. If pmt is omitted, you must include the pv argument.

`Pv`    *Optional*

- The present value, or the lump-sum amount that a series of future payments is worth right now. If pv is omitted, it is assumed to be 0 (zero), and you must include the pmt argument.

`Type`    *Optional*

- The number 0 or 1 and indicates when payments are due. If type is omitted, it is assumed to be 0.

Comment: I agree this is the easiest.  For the benefit of future readers, would you please add a bit of explanation directly to the answer?  That way it will still make sense even if the link becomes invalid (MS has been known to change its links ;) ).

Comment: @cxw Thanks your advice. I repost necessary part of the MS link

Answer (score 1):

As the question is about excel it is possible by

[image: excel math solution]

Or by using the FV function.
FV returns the future value of an investment based on regular payments and a constant interest rate.

Attributes of the FV function;:

- Rate: The interest rate per period.
- Nper: The total number of payment periods in an annuity.
- Pmt: The payment made each period; it cannot change over the life of the annuity. Typically, pmt contains principal and interest but no other fees or taxes. If pmt is omitted, you must include the pv argument.
- Pv: The present value, or the lump-sum amount that a series of future payments is worth right now. If pv is omitted, it is assumed to be 0 (zero), and you must include the pmt argument.
- Type: The number 0 or 1 and indicates when payments are due. If type is omitted, it is assumed to be 0.

Comment: =B1*(1+B2) ^B3 not working for me . it gives 340139.7 for 6 years

Comment: Perhaps B1* POWER(1+B2, B3) works. I was using libreoffice. Will test and update the screenshot

Comment: sorry but =B1*POWER(1+B2,B3) also returns 340139

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way is computing it as a geometric series with the non-financial function [`SERIESSUM`](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Seriessum-Function.html):

```
=SERIESSUM(1.1,0,1,192000*{1,1,1,1,1,1})
```

The rate multiplier is `1.1`, starting from `1.1^0 == 1` and increasing by `1` each year.  The result is `1*a + 1.1*b + 1.1^2*c...`.  The array `192000*{1,1,...}` provides the coefficients `a`, `b`, `c`, ... : one array value for the initial `total_rent = rent`, and one for each subsequent year 1..5 (from `range(1,year)`).